# converting a list of tuples into a dataframe with multi-level columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of namedtuples that I want to convert to a dataframe. The tuples are like this:

```
s = pd.Series({'A': 1, 'B': 2}, 
              pd.Index([u'A', u'B'], 
                       name=u'submission_label'))

SingleExperimentStatistics = namedtuple('SingleExperimentStatistics', 
['metric_name', 'z_score', 'average'])

res = SingleExperimentStatistics(
  metric_name=None, 
  z_score=1.1826795129064109, 
  average=s,
)
```

Calling `pd.Dataframe([res, res])` gives us

```
   metric_name  z_score  average
0  None         1.18268  submission_label A 1 B 2 dtype: int64
1  None         1.18268  submission_label A 1 B 2 dtype: int64
```

But what I want is a pivot table with `MultiIndex` column where `A` and `B` are column names. Basically, something like this:

```
   metric_name  z_score  average
                         A   B   
0  None         1.18268  1   2
1  None         1.18268  1   2
```

What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Note there will be more columns like `average` that have `A` and `B` fields. I have not shown them here to make the problem as small as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to work with a simple index by breaking those series into two columns:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import namedtuple
s = pd.Series({'A': 1, 'B': 2}, 
              pd.Index([u'A', u'B'], 
                       name=u'submission_label'))
SingleExperimentStatistics = namedtuple('SingleExperimentStatistics', 
    ['metric_name', 'z_score', 'average'])
res = SingleExperimentStatistics(
  metric_name=None, 
  z_score=1.1826795129064109, 
  average=s,
)

df = pd.DataFrame([res, res])
df1 = df.loc[:, ['metric_name', 'z_score']]
df1['A'] = df['average'].apply(lambda x: x['A'])
df1['B'] = df['average'].apply(lambda x: x['B'])
print(df1)

  metric_name  z_score  A  B
0        None  1.18268  1  2
1        None  1.18268  1  2
```

If you really want the multi-index, you can define it at this step:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(['metric_name', 'z_score', 'average', 'average'],
                         ['' ,'', 'A', 'B']))
df1.columns = index
print(df1)

  metric_name  z_score average   
                             A  B
0        None  1.18268       1  2
1        None  1.18268       1  2
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I think I need multi index because `average` is not the only column that has `A` and `B` components. I only showed average for the sake of simplicity of the example. 

I have several other columns like num_outliers for A and B. So, I cannot simply flatten everything into simple index without messing with the column names.